# Rearranging the induced norm

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces

I am slightly stuck on getting through the following logic:

$$\max_{x=0}\frac{\lvert Ax \rvert_p}{\lvert x \rvert_p}=\max_{x=0}\lvert A \frac{x}{\lvert x \rvert_p}\rvert_p=\max_{\lvert x \rvert_p=1}\lvert Ax \rvert_p.$$

I understand how we can get from the first to the second step by just using definitions of the norm but I don't understand how we can choose a different max in the last step. Could anyone help me to understand? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me denote by $S$ the set $S=\{\frac{|Ax|_p}{|x|_p},x\neq 0\}$ and by $T$ the set $T=\{|Ax|_p,|x|_p=1\}$. I claim that $T$ and $S$ are *equal*: if true, this implies the desired equality. The fact that $T$ is included in $S$ is obvious. The reverse follows essentially from the way one goes from the first max to the second max: if $s$ is an element of $S$, then $s$ may be written as $s=\frac{|Ax|_p}{|x|_p}$ where $x$ is non-zero, so that $y=\frac{x}{|x|_p}$ is well defined and of norm one and $s=|Ay|_p$ by the properties of the norm (and the presumed linearity of $A$); in particular, $s$ is an element of $T$.

The point is that although they are indexed differently, you are actually contemplating maxes of sets of real numbers and the same properties of the norm (and linearity) that allow one to go from the first max to the second also allow one to conclude that these sets are equal.